# How to stop Redfish Event service cannot deliver .. events in lifecycle log

Tags: bios

Problem
BMC keeps prompting these events,  do you know how to disable them?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. git clone https://github.com/dell/iDRAC-Redfish-Scripting.git
2. cd iDRAC-Redfish-Scripting/Redfish\ Python/
3. create virtual environment for python: python3 -m venv venv
4. source venv/bin/activate
5. pip install requests
6. list subscriptions: $ python3 SubmitTestEventREDFISH.py -ip i<drac
   dns/or IP> -u USER -p PASSWORD -s yy
   let's assume one of the subscriptions is:  /redfish/v1/EventService/Subscriptions/5c3645d8-c1c7-11ec-87be-f40270ade6ea
7. for each subscription, delete: python3 SubmitTestEventREDFISH.py -ip
   i<drac dns/or IP> -u USER -p PASSWORD  --delete
   /redfish/v1/EventService/Subscriptions/5c3645d8-c1c7-11ec-87be-f40270ade6ea
8. Now repeat 6 to verify it is removed.

Wish stackoverflow had a redfish tag for this post....